# Do i need to format my pc before installing mcafee antivirus?

Tags: windows-8, virus, anti-virus

Recently brought McAfee antivirus plus 2013.

I was wondering if I first need to format my laptop(win 8) before installing it. Or it does it not matter if in case there is some viruses present on my PC like the viruses infecting windows core files and cant be detected by McAfee.

It is written on the box - "product can be install on 1 PC (only one OS per PC)". 
Does this  mean that I can not reuse it if I reformat my PC that if in future

I came with this dilemma as i have 200GB of saved data.

Please advice do i really need to format my PC ? I have read somewhere "If your windows operating system files have been infected chances are the antivirus software cannot remove the infected system files as windows are using them. This means you'll have to reinstall windows first to get rid of the infected files. "

Comment: Possibly, but I treat it as it can be used on 1 PC, not installed once. However, license questions are off topic here (since each version of the software may have a different license)

Comment: It probably means that you can only install it on one OS ion the PC (so no installing it on multiple OS on the same PC (multiboot) or on a lot of VM (which would all be running on the same computer). As to "where would I keep my data". Well, in the same place you keep your backups. ;-)

Comment: It simply means it can only be activated on a single computer.  If 2 computers with it installed are activated, one of them, will fail to be activated and be unlicensed.

Answer (score 2):

#### "Product can be installed on 1 PC (only one OS per PC)"

It means that you won't be able to activated the product on another PC with the same license key. If you uninstall the antivirus on the first computer you should be able to install and activate it on another one.

So, if you format your PC you should be able to install the antivirus again with no problems.

#### Formatting before installation

If you already have some infected files, McAfee should be able to detect and clean them. Formatting won't really matter (if the viruses are undetectable by McAfee) because you can just accidentally download them again (...because they are undetectable by McAfee).

#### P.S - McAfee Test Statistics

According to [AV Comparatives](http://www.av-comparatives.org), McAfee got 96.8% protection rate in the "real world protection test" and 98.0% detection rate at the "on-demand file detection test". **So it will probably detect the viruses you may already have in your PC.**

[image: Real-world protection test - 96.8% (Aug 2013)]

[image: File detection test - 98.0% (Mar 2013)]

To summarize, McAfee got the "Advanced" tag, with 2 out of 3 start at AV-Comparatives, on both tests.

[image: ADVANCED - On-demand detection test. 2 out of 3 stars.]                 [image: ADVANCED - Real-world protection test. 2 out of 3 stars.]

So again: McAfee will probably detect any virus/malware that you might have obtained prior to the installation.

Comment: i have read somewhere "If your windows operating system files have been infected chances are the antivirus software cannot remove the infected system files as windows are using them. This means you'll have to reinstall windows first to get rid of the infected files."

Comment: The antivirus should be able to fix these kind of issues too. That's why sometimes it asks you to **reboot** your PC, so it can remove the files in boot time, before Windows starts. (If the antivirus has found viruses that windows uses and therefore can't remove)

Comment: @khwaish: the concern is more drivers than system files, but yes, it is possible for either to become infected in almost invisible ways. windows files are all signed however, so that makes it harder to replace them. you have to trick the system into believing the altered binary is signed and has an expected signature.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can reinstall it after a system format. "product can be install on 1 PC (only one OS per PC)" means that you can install it only on a single pc, not on a single pc - one time.